# How to determine the moment of a single force acting on a free rigid body, not colinear with the center of mass?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

Suppose we have a uniform, solid, non-rotating sphere with moment of Inertia $I$ http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/isph.html and with a radially protruding ideally rigid bar of negligible mass.  Let the sphere be at rest in deep space relative to the observer inertial frame.   Let a force act perpendicular to the bar at distance $r$ from the center of the sphere.  Clearly, the sphere will begin to rotate.  More subtely, the sphere must also acquire translational momentum equal to $fdt$ for the the force $f$ acting for the infinitesimal period $dt$.

Typically, text books describe torque as resulting from a couple of opposing, non-colinear external force components acting on a rigid body.  The implication being, if we have a torque, we have a couple.  We might try the "inertial force" resulting from the body's resistance to being accelerated, as our second force in the couple.  But that can't be exactly equal and opposite to the applied force, and acting at the center of mass, since that would necessarily leave the center of mass at rest.

So how do we determine the torque causing the sphere to acquire angular momentum?

Comment: Re: the edit: I actually did mean "couple", even though "moment" may be the more appropriate term.  That is, I expect there is a way of describing the system using a pair of "force" vectors, even if one of them is a pseudo-force.  But I'll accept the change.